# How to click this button with python & selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm looking to click the button highlighted in the screenshot below; have tried with pyautogui but found results to be inconsistent so trying selenium instead.

I'm having trouble identifying the button to then call the click function.

[Here's the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtoMj.jpg)
Alternatively perhaps I could run the 'ng-click' function, unsure how to approach that. If I do this, I'll need to pipe through 'index', from what I can tell from this HTML (my understanding of HTML is minimal)

Thank you

Comment: you should think about providing your code/tries and output and explain why it doesnt have the good effect.

Comment: have you looked into a web scraper like beautiful soup? It has the ability to press buttons and helps with getting information from a site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have browser to figure out the button CSS selector for you.

Here's how to do that in Chrome:

- Open your page in Chrome
- Right-click on your button and select the **Inspect Element** from the context menu
- The Inspector window will open with the button's HTML markup selected.
- Right-click the selected HTML line(s) and select **Copy -> CSS Selector**.
- Paste the CSS selector into the code below

And here's the code to click your button:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
browser.get('your/website/url')
button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('paste the CSS selector here')
button.click()
```

Hope this helps.

PS: Here's an excellent [article](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/) (a chapter from the **Automate the boring stuff with Python** book) on web scraping and browser automation using BeautifulSoap and Selenuim.

Comment: thanks very much - this method of finding the CSS selector worked beautifully. I love ATBS too.

Answer (score 0):

Try for `xpath` as:
 `//div[@id='channel']//div[@class='channel-list']/div/div/div[@class='ch-btn play']`

or

`//div[@id='channel']//div[@class='channel-list']//div[@class='ch-btn play']`

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use CSS Selectors, as they are preferred in selenium over Xpath. Some important notes about html and selenium:

- Html is a static language. There is not way to "call" or "run" things in it. That requires use of a different language, like JavaScript.
- Selenium mimics an actual user, so selenium is not directly "calling" anything, it is interacting with the page, and the page responds.

python code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('path/to/chromedriver')
driver.get('your/site/here')
# This is a css selector for the div that you want to click on.
css_selector = "div[ng-click='play($index)']"
# This finds the object that is located at css_selector
button_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector)
# Sends a mouse click to the button_element
button_element.click()
```