# How to find and click on a button with reference to parent using selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to find and click on a button using selenium in python. I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656607/how-to-click-this-button-with-python-selenium) to inspect element of that button which leads me to the following block:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-bind="click:$parent.select"><!--mm text:$root.lang('searchSelect')-->Select<!--/mm-->
```

After copying this with Copy->copy selector and pasting it in my code I get:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.container-fluid > section:nth-child(7) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(12) > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div.col-sm-3.text-center > button').click()
```

Outcome: No error but the button is not being clicked. What am I doing wrong?

P.S To **scrape** results earlier in the code I manually looked at pagesource and did::

```
results = soup.select('.panel-body .col-xs-6 strong')[0].get_text()
```

Comment: Can you provide the link to the web page you are working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's never recommended to use the absolute path to the element. You should always use relative path. Both using `xpath` or `css selectors`.
Personally I prefer using `xpath` where if the element's parent can be located with `//tag[@attrubute='value']` and the child element is `//child_tag[@child_att='val1']` so the child relatively to the parent will be located simply by `//tag[@attrubute='value']//child_tag[@child_att='val1']`

Comment: Ok. I will look into xpath. Thanks. Also, can I open a chrome window and the same website and find the outcome of the button clicked? I mean I can click the button in the code but how do I see this outcome in an actual browser window?

Comment: I can't answer you since I don't know what is that button do. It would be better if you provide the link to that web page and ask more specific questions.

Comment: Ok. But can you answer in general. How do you start an actual chrome session (from python) based on the actions (searches, clicks etc) you make in python with selenium?

Comment: Very generally: open the browser, get the web page by passing the driver the URL. Then wait for appearance / clickability / visibility of the desired element then click it or get it's text / any other attribute. It's not depended the language you are using

Comment: Cheers, I am doing that already. What I mean is how do I open a graphical outcome of my changes in a an actual browser window? The changes in code are all fine but I want to proceed by opening an actual chrome window with the desired changes (searches, clicks) I made in the code

Comment: I really do not understand what are you asking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can search by Xpath, to do it, just inspect the html control (your button) and right click its html object "Copy>Copy FullXpath", then, in your code:

```
control = diver.find_element_by_xpath("[XPATH]")
control.click()
```

this worked for me, here and example from my own:

```
logging_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[1]')
logging_button.click()
```

Comment: Your welcome, you can upvote the answer to help other people with same problem. :)